# My leg bones don't seem to be working properly? (from what I know)

Tags: animation, bones, eevee-render-engine, blend-files

I saw a nice model and I decided to check her out and animate her, but the legs weren't moving the way all the other models legs that I have imported looked like. ([video](https://gyazo.com/e25c22877736fac3df5ebfe13460dd25))

First off, her leg isn't supposed to move up like that, and second her feet are acting as if the grid is an actual floor. But my point is, they aren't supposed to be constantly moving with the model when I move her leg. It's supposed to stay static unless I decide to move her foot.

I've put a model that actually works and the model I'm using to compare them (pictures below), and I, myself have tried to solve this but I didn't succeed. Since this isn't my model, I am not entirely sure of what they did, but maybe any of you might know?

I am providing the blend file with both models so you can see the comparison up close and maybe even find the difference between them that makes one move properly and the other one not.

Blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oNY-u3omwKBSQtJ4dgYPS6ff9zBmhqq7/view?usp=sharing

How it's supposed to look:
[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

What it actually looks like:
[image: screenshot 3]

[image: screenshot 4]

I'm not sure if I should provide a GIF of me moving the other model's legs, but if I need to I will.

Comment: One of the models has IK legs.  The other doesn't.  (It has an IK foot, but not IK legs.)  This is why the legs animate in different ways.  To animate the second model, you need to use a different animation, one based on FK animation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an MMD model, so it may be why the rig acts a bit different than usual...

In that case, select and move the IK bone of the Foot to animate, instead of the leg bone: [this bone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWEn2.png)